# REGEX to find STRING between two values

Tags: regex, string, substring

I have a string being received from a monitoring system, the string contains 3 variables that I am interested in the variables are *pre/post fixed* with `c=VAR1; e=VAR2; s=VAR3;` so I want to grab the text in between for example *c=* ; but am having limited success, these are a few of the REGEXs I have tested with:

```
c=([^;]+);
.+c=(.+);.+
(?<=c=\()(.*?)(?=\;*\))
c=(.*);
```

A full alert string would look similar to:

```
alert c=Vari Able1; e=Vari Able2; s=Vari Able3;
```

But none seem to return in the way I would expect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
(\w+)=([^;]+)
```

Which would grab all values (key and value), but if you're after only the c value:

```
c=([^;]+)
```

Should capture everything between the `=` and `;` (`([^;]+)` captures every character that's not a semi-colon, repeated 1 or more times.).

Comment: @Isaac: Oops, typo. Yes, forgot the quantifier. Good catch.

Comment: @Isaac: Lol, indeed. Can you tell it's after 5? ;p

Comment: This seems like it should do what I need and when I run it in a REGEX tester it finds what I need but it isn't working in the native tool I am using for this work, however that's not your problem so thank you for your answer!

Comment: @AndrewReynolds: Where is the application? There are different versions and applications of REGEX. Unfortunately there is no "one size fits all", though 90% of the patterns translate cross-platform/application.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex is good, but only working for `c` variable, this is a variation working for all three variables:

```
[ces]=([^;]+);
```

that will look for your c , e and s variables.

In **PHP** you could execute it like this:

```
$string = 'c=VAR1; e=VAR2; s=VAR3;';
preg_match_all("/([ces])=([^;]+);/", $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$tot = count($out[1]);
for ($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++) {
    echo $out[1][$i]; //will echo 'c' , 'e' , 's' respectively
    echo $out[2][$i]; //will echo 'VAR1' , 'VAR2' , 'VAR3' respectively
}
```

**Update**: Answer to a OP's question in comments

The above loop is for dinamically assign the values found, so if the regex found 4 , 5 or 10 vars the for will loop all of them. But if you are sure your string has only 3 vars in it, you could assign them directly in one go, like this:

```
$string = 'c=VAR1; e=VAR2; s=VAR3;';
preg_match_all("/([ces])=([^;]+);/", $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$$out[1][0] = $out[2][0]; // var $c is created with VAR1 value
$$out[1][1] = $out[2][1]; // var $e is created with VAR1 value
$$out[1][2] = $out[2][2]; // var $s is created with VAR1 value

echo $c; //will output VAR1
echo $e; //will output VAR2
echo $s; //will output VAR3
```

I'm using PHP [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in above code.

Comment: Question on this - would doing them in one hit allow me assign them to separate variables? Or would it only ever find the first one, I see in your PHP you have a FOR loop counter so I assume this is how you assign each of them but in the native tool I am using for my work that isn't possible I have 3 variables all running a slightly different REGEX on the same string to pick out the text it is interested in.

Comment: I updated my answer to include your question about FOR loop, consider giving upvote if you find it useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
(?<=((alert)?.*=)).*?(?=;)
```

See **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

RegexBuddy ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: So this one gives me: REGEX: Compile failed at offset 18: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length as an error in my debugger

Answer (score 0):

So the ultimate solution to this question was I need to find out a little more about the tool I was using, specifically the REGEX engine... as it turns out it uses PCRE so the final REGEX was:

```
'(?<=c=)[^;]*'
'(?<=e=)[^;]*'
'(?<=s=)[^;]*'
```

In the tool that exists within the software I was reconfiguring this gave me the three variables I needed to correctly interpret my monitor system alerts.

Thanks all!